# How does $R \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ h)\ $?

Tags: lie-algebras, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, universal-algebra, quantization

**Definition** $:$ Let $H$ be a Hopf algebra. An invertible element $R \in H \otimes H$ is called a coboundary structure on $H$ if

$(1)$ $\Delta^{\text {op}} = R \Delta R^{-1},$

$(2)$ $R_{21} = R^{-1},$

$(3)$ $R_{12} (\Delta \otimes 1) R = R_{23} (1 \otimes \Delta) R.$

We will call the pair $(H, R)$ a coboundary Hopf algebra.

> **Proposition** $:$ Let $H$ be a quantized universal enveloping algebra which is a quantization of the Lie bialgebra $(\mathfrak g, [\cdot, \cdot], \delta).$ If $R$ is a coboundary structure on $H,$ then the element $r \in U (\mathfrak g) \otimes U (\mathfrak g)$ defined by $$R \equiv 1 + hr\ (\text {mod}\ h^2)$$ is in fact in $\bigwedge^2 \mathfrak g$ and is a coboundary structure on $\mathfrak g.$

The proof of the proposition is the following $:$

[image]

In this proof how do the authors guarantee the existence of such an $r \in U (\mathfrak g) \otimes U (\mathfrak g)\ $? By the given condition we have $$r \equiv \frac {R - 1} {h}\ (\text {mod}\ h).$$ In order for such an $r$ to exist we should have $R \equiv 1\ (\text {mod}\ h).$ But how does the given condition ensure that? Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks a bunch!

**Source** $:$ *Lectures on Quantum Groups* by Pavel Etingof and Oliver Schiffmann.

Comment: Let $\rho$ be the reduction of $R$ modulo $h$. Then $\rho$ is a coboundary structure on $U(g)$. But the only invertible elements in $U(g)^{\otimes 2}$ are the scalar, and the coboundary axioms forces this scalar to be 1 I think.

Comment: @Adrien$:$ Could you please elaborate as to why the invertible elements of $U (\mathfrak g)^{\otimes 2}$ are all scalars? Is it due to PBW?

Comment: @Adrien$:$ What I got is $\rho = \pm 1$ by using $\rho \rho_{21} = 1.$

Comment: @Adrien$:$ In fact if $\rho = - 1$ then the coboundary structure $r$ on $\mathfrak g$ is given by $$r \equiv - \frac {R + 1} {h}\ (\text {mod}\ h)$$ and, with this assumption no axiom of coboundary structure is violated. So this is an equally valid option i.e. the constant coefficient of $R$ may as well be $-1.$ I think the author forgot to treat this case separately.

Comment: Isn't $(\epsilon \otimes \operatorname{id})(R)=1$ also part of the axioms of a coboundary Hopf algebra ?

Comment: @Adrien$:$ This axiom is not there in the book.

Comment: I see, I've checked other references and it wasn't always there, though sometimes it is (eg https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0603740). I feel it should be, and the thing is it's automatic for quasi-triangular Hopf algebra so this might be a source of confusion. There is a general notion of a commutatif on a monoidal category $C$ which is a monoidal structure on the identity functor seen as a functor $C\rightarrow C^{mop}$ where "mop" means the opposite tensor product. Braiding and coboundary structure should both be particular cases of that: a coboundary structure is an involutive commutor.

Comment: (sorry, a notion of "commutor" not "commutatif"). Now the definition of a monoidal structure on a functor does include this compatibility with the unit, as it should of course.

Comment: The braidings on the category of (“admissible”) finite dimensional representations of a quantization of g is parametrized by antisymmetric bicharacters on the P/Q, for the weight lattice and the root lattice. Like Adrien says, it’s a sensible convention to ask for R = 1 mod h from the beginning. (But you can also see that the other “R-matrices” corresponding to nontrivial characters do not live in a deformation of U(g), only in a certain completion.)